# How to redirect to another page after submitting the ctools modal form

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Actually i want to redirect to some other page after submitting the multistep ctools modal form .I have tried using form_state['redirect] and drupal_goto in submit function but didnt work.

```
function get_quote_menu(){

$items=array();
$items['get_quote'] = array(
  'title' => 'Get Quotation',
  'page callback' => 'get_quote_form',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
$items['get_quote/%ctools_js/details'] = array(
  'title' => 'Get Quotation',
  'page callback' => 'quote_ajax_details_form',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
}
function quote_ajax_details_form($js = NULL, $step = NULL){

if ($js) {

    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
 }
  $form_info=array(

    'id' => 'quote_details',
    'path' => "get_quote/" . ($js ? 'ajax' : 'nojs') . "/details/%step",
    'show trail' => TRUE,
    'show back' => TRUE,
    'show cancel' => TRUE,
    'show return' => FALSE,
    'next callback' =>  'get_quote_details_next',
    'finish callback' => 'get_quote_details_finish',
    'cancel callback' => 'get_quote_details_cancel',    

    'order' => array(
        'start' => t('View the plans and premiums best suited to you <br/>in 4 straight forward steps.'),
        'second'=>t(''),
    ),

    'forms' => array(
        'start' => array(
            'form id' => 'get_quote_start',
       ),
       'second'=>array(
            'form id'=> 'get_actual_quote_details',
       )
    ),
);

$object_id = 1;

if (empty($step)) {
// We reset the form when $step is NULL because that means they have
// for whatever reason started over.
get_quote_cache_clear($object_id);
$step = 'start';
}

// This automatically gets defaults if there wasn't anything saved.
$object = get_quote_cache_get($object_id);


$form_state = array(
'ajax' => $js,
// Put our object and ID into the form state cache so we can easily find
// it.
'object_id' => $object_id,
'object' => &$object,
);


ctools_include('wizard');
$form = ctools_wizard_multistep_form($form_info, $step, $form_state);
$output = drupal_render($form);

if($js){

$commands=array();

if($output===FALSE  || !empty($form_state['complete'])){


  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#ctools-sample', finish($form_state['object']));
  $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();    

}else if(!empty($form_state['cancel'])) {

    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();

}else {

     $commands = ctools_modal_form_render($form_state, $output);
}

 print ajax_render($commands);
 exit; 
}else{

 return $output;

 }
}
 function get_quote_start($form, &$form_state){
            $form['first_name'] = array(

'#title' => t('Your Name'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#size'=>20,
'#default_value' => $form_state['object']->first_name,
'#attributes'=>array(
    'placeholder'=>t('First Name'),
    'id'=>array('quote-first-name'),
),
//'#required'=>true,
);
$form['middle_name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#default_value' => $form_state['object']->middle_name,
'#size'=>20,
'#attributes'=>array(
    'placeholder'=>t('Middle Name'),
    'id'=>array('quote-middle-name'),
 ),
//'#required'=>true,
);
 return $form;
}
 function get_quote_start_submit(&$form, &$form_state){

global $user;


 $form_state['object']->uid=$user->uid;
}
function get_actual_quote_details($form, &$form_state){
$form['adults']=array(

    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title' => t('Adults'),
    '#options'=>array(
        1=>1,
        2=>2,
        3=>3,
    ),

 );
return $form;
}
function get_actual_quote_details_submit(&$form, &$form_state){

    // Not working redirect 
       // drupal_goto('node/add/page');
        $form_state['redirect]='node/add/page',
}
```

Comment: can you post your code with this question?!

Comment: @Aboodred1 I have attached the code above .Pls have a look

Comment: Finally after some research i have solved the issue using ctools api.I have implemented below code in mine form submit handler.  ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
    $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('node/add/page');// Redirect to url u want.
    print ajax_render($commands);
    exit;

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but hopefully it'll help someone. Down where you write your commands[] array. Change it to something like this. In the submit function of one of the earlier forms I set the redirectpath parameter on the object, then i just use that in ctools_ajax_command_redirect() after calling the dismiss modal function ctools_modal_command_dismiss().

```
  // If $output is FALSE, there was no actual form.
  $commands = array();
  if ($output === FALSE || !empty($form_state['complete'])) {
    // Dismiss the modal.
    $finish = _aap_main_add_finish($form_state['object']);
    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#ctools-sample', $finish);
    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($form_state['object']->redirectpath);
  }
  else if (!empty($form_state['cancel'])) {
    // If cancelling, return to the activity.
    $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
  }
  else {
    $commands = ctools_modal_form_render($form_state, $output);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add destination for links.
I have also similar problem with drual modal form. After user registration and forgot password I have to send it on thanks page.
Create tpl file and make registration link using below code.

```
<?php
echo l('Sign up here', 'user/register', array('query'=>array('destination'=>'thanks')));
?>
```

Create tpl file and make forgot password link using below code.

```
<?php
print l('Forgot Your Password?', 'user/password', array('query'=>array('destination'=>'thanks')));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hitesh Jain : Thank you for the answer. Your comment helped me.
Just adding this as an answer so that it can help others.

`ctools_include('ajax');`
`ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');`
`$commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect('node/add/page');`
`// Redirect to url u want.`
`print ajax_render($commands);`
`exit;`

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you strongly to use [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rule)  module. there is no need to programming, simply add event and action and it works great.